# How to run ASP.NET MVC Web API controller method by query parameter value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, routes

Im trying to run controller method based on query parameters instead normal route (e.g.": MyController\DoSomething) but getting error. How solve this problem?

```
[Route("MyController?Command=DoTask1")]
public IHttpActionResult Task1()
{ 
    return Ok();
}

[Route("MyController?Command=DoTask2")]
public IHttpActionResult Task2()
{ 
    return Ok();
}
....
```

Comment: Do you need to use this specific implementation? Why not use "normal" routes? If you just want to derive the type of command from the query parameter, you could create a single endpoint accepting a `Command` parameter and then call `Task1()` or `Task2()` according to the value of that parameter

Comment: @devNull, Im using this way because of client already using this type of route. Also I considered single endpoint accepting way but, it hard to control different request models, i think.

Comment: @IbnAdam what do you mean by request models? Data you pass to controller action or return from here? If input data - it is not clear from your Question that you want pass something to controller. If you mean output data - anything could be returned with ActionResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Hello(string command)
        {
            switch (command.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "dotask1":
                    Task1();break;
                case "dotask2":
                    Task2(); break;
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        private void Task1()
        {

        }
        private void Task2()
        {

        }
    }
```

This way you'll have only one endpoint and those routes would be valid :

/my?command=DoTask1

/my?command=DoTask2

etc